# perlにて、2つの要素からなる配列のリファレンスの配列から、0番目の要素の値が最大の1番目の要素を取得したい。

Tags: array, perl

例えば（[1,'A'],[2,'B'],.....,[10,'X'])のとき、'X'を取り出すには、どうしたらいいでしょうか？
forループでごりごりやればできますが、map、grep、maxのような関数を使ってエレガントに記述したいのですが。

Comment: ソートするのはどうでしょう。`my @sorted = sort { @$b[0] <=> @$a[0] } @arr; print $sorted[0][1];`

Comment: ありがとうございます。簡潔に記述できています。最大値を求めるのにソートするのは無駄が多いようにも思いますが、Perl内部の処理で、かつ単純なソートですからいいのですかね。。。

Comment: 以下のような記述でもできますね。    use List::Util qw/reduce/;    my $list_max = reduce { $a->[0]>$b->[0] ? $a : $b } @arr;     print $list_max->[1];

Comment: それを回答として書いてみてはどうでしょう(自己回答をご自身で承認することが可能です)。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-COREなCPANモジュールを使えるのなら `List::UtilsBy` の`max_by`がそのものずばりです。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy qw(max_by);

my @arr = (
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D'],
    [5, 'E'],
    [10, 'X'],
);

my $max = max_by { $_->[0] } @arr;
print $max->[1];
```

List::UtilsByの利点はmaxとなる要素が複数ある場合にも対応できることです。

```
my @arr = (
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D'],
    [5, 'E'],
    [10, 'X'],
    [10, 'Z'],
);

my @max = max_by { $_->[0] } @arr;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @max;
__END__
$VAR1 = [
          10,
          'X'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          10,
          'Z'
        ];
```

`max_by` 自体は実装も簡潔なので、COREモジュールが使えない場合サブルーチンだけ拝借してもいいかもしれません。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    # Borrowed from List::UtilsBy@0.11
    sub max_by(&@)
    {
       my $code = shift;

       return unless @_;

       local $_;

       my @maximal = $_ = shift @_;
       my $max     = $code->( $_ );

       foreach ( @_ ) {
          my $this = $code->( $_ );
          if( $this > $max ) {
             @maximal = $_;
             $max     = $this;
          }
          elsif( wantarray and $this == $max ) {
             push @maximal, $_;
          }
       }

       return wantarray ? @maximal : $maximal[0];
    }
}

my @arr = (
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D'],
    [5, 'E'],
    [10, 'X'],
);

my $max = max_by { $_->[0] } @arr;
print $max->[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

自己回答ですが、List::Util のreduceを使って、

```
 (reduce { $a->[0]>$b->[0] ? $a : $b } @arr)->[1];
```

と書けます。
metropolisさんのコメントを参考にさせていただきました。